# Посчитать разницу по таблице

Tags: javascript, jquery

```css
.nav_data{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 48px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e6e9;
    background: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.nav_data .add_btn{
    width: 48px;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    color: #99a8c0;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 48px;
}
.im-page--history .content_data{
    padding:15px;
}
.search_field {
    height: 48px;
    background: url(assets/img/search-icon.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: 10px center;
    padding-left: 35px;
    color: #000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 18px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e8ec;
}
.im-page {
    height: 500px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}
.user_list{
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
}
.user_list li{
    display: flex;
    height: 63px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 0 0 15px;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.user_list li:hover {
    border-top: solid 1px #e7e8ec;
    background-color: #f5f7fa;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #e7e8ec;
}
.user_list li:hover .info-block {
    border-color: transparent;
}
.user_list li .info-block{
margin-left: 10px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
     border-top: solid 1px transparent;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #e7e8ec;
    padding: 8px 15px 8px 0;
    position: relative;
    width: calc(100% - 85px);
}
.user_list li .info-block span.name  {
color: #222;
    max-width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.im-block{
    width: 46px;
    height: 46px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 9px 7px 8px 0;
    -moz-force-broken-image-icon: 0;
    background-color: #fafbfc;
    background-color: inherit;
    border: 1px solid;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.im-page .im-page--dialogs {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 48px 0 45px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}
.im-page .im-page--history {
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.page_block {
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #d7d8db, 0 0 0 1px #e3e4e8;
    margin: 0;
}
.im-page--list{
    position: fixed;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #d7d8db, 0 0 0 1px #e3e4e8;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 999;

}

#block-edit-copy {
    display: none !important;
}
.block-edit{
       position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    background-color: #3b3b54;
    display: flex;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 3px; 
}
.have-select {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.have-select span {
  display: none;
}

td[data-name="hdate"],td[data-name="pdate"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 320px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #38678f;
}
th {
    background: #878c90;
    height: 45px;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #717477;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 18px;
}
tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
td {
    border-right: 1px solid #cccccc;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table  class="heavyTable" contenteditable="true" data-table="1">
                    <thead>
                        <th>Дата прихода</th>
                        <th>Дата продаж</th>
                        <th>Продажа ст</th>
                        <th>Дебит</th>
                        <th>Кредит</th>
                        <th>Баланс</th>
                        <th>Брак ст</th>
                        <th>Брак сумма</th>
                        <th>Сальдо</th>
                        <th>Приход сумма</th>
                        <th>Сальдо об.</th>
                        <th>Приход ст</th>
                        <th>Остаток ст</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr data-id="1" data-table="1" data-new="0">
                         <td data-name="hdate"><span>Не указано</span></td>
                         <td data-name="pdate">2</td>
                         <td data-name="sale">3</td>
                         <td data-name="debit">2</td>
                         <td data-name="credit">3</td>
                         <td data-name="balanse">1</td>
                         <td data-name="brakst">2</td>
                         <td data-name="braksumma">3</td>
                         <td data-name="saldok">3</td>
                         <td data-name="prihodsumma">1</td>
                         <td data-name="saldo">2</td>
                         <td data-name="prihodst">3</td>
                         <td data-name="ostatokst">3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr data-id="2" data-table="1" data-new="0">
                         <td data-name="hdate">1</td>
                         <td data-name="pdate">2</td>
                         <td data-name="sale">3</td>
                         <td data-name="debit">2</td>
                         <td data-name="row">3</td>
                         <td data-name="balanse">1</td>
                         <td data-name="brakst">2</td>
                         <td data-name="braksumma">3</td>
                         <td data-name="saldok">3</td>
                         <td data-name="prihodsumma">1</td>
                         <td data-name="saldo">2</td>
                         <td data-name="prihodst">3</td>
                         <td data-name="ostatokst">3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr data-id="37" data-table="2" data-new="0">
                         <td data-name="hdate">1</td>
                         <td data-name="pdate">2</td>
                         <td data-name="sale">3</td>
                         <td data-name="debit">2</td>
                         <td data-name="credit">3</td>
                         <td data-name="balanse">1</td>
                         <td data-name="brakst">2</td>
                         <td data-name="braksumma">3</td>
                         <td data-name="saldok">3</td>
                         <td data-name="prihodsumma">1</td>
                         <td data-name="saldo">2</td>
                         <td data-name="prihodst">3</td>
                         <td data-name="ostatokst">3</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

как мне при вводе в поля и при редактировании считать значение ячейки `saldok = debit - credit - braksumma`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал красиво, через [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), крутая штука. Пробуйте вводить, все считается.

```js
const observer = new MutationObserver(function (e) {
  const td = e[0].target.parentNode
  
  if (!td)
    return
    
  const tr = td.closest('tr')
  const values = [...elements].filter(i => tr.contains(i)).map(i => +i.textContent)
  
  console.log(values.join())
  const id = tr.dataset.id
  const result = values.reduce((a, b) => a - b) // saldok = debit - credit - braksumma
  
  document.querySelector(`tr[data-id="${id}"] > td[data-name="saldok"]`).textContent = result
})

const td = ['debit', 'credit', 'braksumma']
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(td.map((item, i) => `td[data-name=${item}] `))


elements.forEach(i => {
  observer.observe(i, {
    subtree: true,
    childList: true,
    characterData: true,
    //characterDataOldValue: true
  })
})
```

```css
.nav_data{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 48px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e6e9;
    background: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.nav_data .add_btn{
    width: 48px;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    color: #99a8c0;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 48px;
}
.im-page--history .content_data{
    padding:15px;
}
.search_field {
    height: 48px;
    background: url(assets/img/search-icon.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: 10px center;
    padding-left: 35px;
    color: #000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 18px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e8ec;
}
.im-page {
    height: 500px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}
.user_list{
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
}
.user_list li{
    display: flex;
    height: 63px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 0 0 15px;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.user_list li:hover {
    border-top: solid 1px #e7e8ec;
    background-color: #f5f7fa;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #e7e8ec;
}
.user_list li:hover .info-block {
    border-color: transparent;
}
.user_list li .info-block{
margin-left: 10px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
     border-top: solid 1px transparent;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #e7e8ec;
    padding: 8px 15px 8px 0;
    position: relative;
    width: calc(100% - 85px);
}
.user_list li .info-block span.name  {
color: #222;
    max-width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.im-block{
    width: 46px;
    height: 46px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 9px 7px 8px 0;
    -moz-force-broken-image-icon: 0;
    background-color: #fafbfc;
    background-color: inherit;
    border: 1px solid;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.im-page .im-page--dialogs {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 48px 0 45px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}
.im-page .im-page--history {
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.page_block {
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #d7d8db, 0 0 0 1px #e3e4e8;
    margin: 0;
}
.im-page--list{
    position: fixed;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #d7d8db, 0 0 0 1px #e3e4e8;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 999;

}

#block-edit-copy {
    display: none !important;
}
.block-edit{
       position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    background-color: #3b3b54;
    display: flex;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 3px; 
}
.have-select {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.have-select span {
  display: none;
}

td[data-name="hdate"],td[data-name="pdate"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 320px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #38678f;
}
th {
    background: #878c90;
    height: 45px;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #717477;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 18px;
}
tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
td {
    border-right: 1px solid #cccccc;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table  class="heavyTable" contenteditable="true" data-table="1">
                    <thead>
                        <th>Дата прихода</th>
                        <th>Дата продаж</th>
                        <th>Продажа ст</th>
                        <th>Дебит</th>
                        <th>Кредит</th>
                        <th>Баланс</th>
                        <th>Брак ст</th>
                        <th>Брак сумма</th>
                        <th>Сальдо</th>
                        <th>Приход сумма</th>
                        <th>Сальдо об.</th>
                        <th>Приход ст</th>
                        <th>Остаток ст</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr data-id="1" data-table="1" data-new="0">
                         <td data-name="hdate"><span>Не указано</span></td>
                         <td data-name="pdate">2</td>
                         <td data-name="sale">3</td>
                         <td data-name="debit">100</td>
                         <td data-name="credit">50</td>
                         <td data-name="balanse">1</td>
                         <td data-name="brakst">2</td>
                         <td data-name="braksumma">20</td>
                         <td data-name="saldok">3</td>
                         <td data-name="prihodsumma">1</td>
                         <td data-name="saldo">2</td>
                         <td data-name="prihodst">3</td>
                         <td data-name="ostatokst">3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr data-id="2" data-table="1" data-new="0">
                         <td data-name="hdate">1</td>
                         <td data-name="pdate">2</td>
                         <td data-name="sale">3</td>
                         <td data-name="debit">50</td>
                         <td data-name="credit">10</td>
                         <td data-name="balanse">1</td>
                         <td data-name="brakst">2</td>
                         <td data-name="braksumma">10</td>
                         <td data-name="saldok">3</td>
                         <td data-name="prihodsumma">1</td>
                         <td data-name="saldo">30</td>
                         <td data-name="prihodst">3</td>
                         <td data-name="ostatokst">3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr data-id="37" data-table="2" data-new="0">
                         <td data-name="hdate">1</td>
                         <td data-name="pdate">2</td>
                         <td data-name="sale">3</td>
                         <td data-name="debit">10</td>
                         <td data-name="credit">5</td>
                         <td data-name="balanse">1</td>
                         <td data-name="brakst">2</td>
                         <td data-name="braksumma">5</td>
                         <td data-name="saldok">3</td>
                         <td data-name="prihodsumma">1</td>
                         <td data-name="saldo">0</td>
                         <td data-name="prihodst">3</td>
                         <td data-name="ostatokst">3</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: этот код почему то у меня результат выводит в saldo первого tr